# Selecting dropdown list box invisible items

Tags: selenium, primefaces, listbox, dropdown

How to select a invisible dropdown list drop from following code?

```
<div id="form:munit_panel" class="ui-selectonemenu-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow" style="width: 125px; display: block; top: 177px; left: 798.267px; z-index: 1006;">
<div class="ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper" style="height:200px">
<ul id="form:munit_items" class="ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="form:munit_0">
<li id="form:munit_0" class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-label="No Unit">No Unit</li>
<li id="form:munit_1" class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-label="Bag">Bag</li>
<li id="form:munit_2" class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-label="Load">Load</li>
<li id="form:munit_3" class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-label="Litre">Litre</li>
<li id="form:munit_4" class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-label="Each">Each</li>
<li id="form:munit_5" class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-label="Unit">Unit</li>
<li id="form:munit_6" class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-label="Nos">Nos</li>
<li id="form:munit_7" class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-label="R.feet">R.feet</li>
<li id="form:munit_8" class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-label="Sq.ft">Sq.ft</li>
<li id="form:munit_9" class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-label="Kgs">Kgs</li>
<li id="form:munit_10" class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-label="feet">feet</li>
<li id="form:munit_11" class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-label="ml">ml</li>
<li id="form:munit_12" class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-label="Mts">Mts</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried this Selenium code to select the dropdown last option:

```
public void selectOneMenu(String idPrefix, String value) {
        if (StringUtil.isNotBlank(value)) {
            driver.findElement(By.id(idPrefix + "_label")).click();
            driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath("//div[@id='" + idPrefix
                            + "_panel']/div/ul/li[text()='" + value + "']"))
                    .click();
        }
 }
```

[image: drop down list box, with invisible list snap]

Comment: What do you mean invisible items?? and what have you tried so far??

Comment: i need to select the last option in the dropdown list box .when i click the drop down box 12 th item is not visible !!

Comment: So far i tried this code!1

Comment: Provide the exception being thrown. Also is the problem with only last options or with all the options in the dropdown ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) to wait until `dropdown` options visible and enable to click after clicking on `dropdown` as below :-

```
public void selectOptionsByIdFromDropdown(String dropdownId, String optionsId) {

   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

  //First click on dropdown menu
  WebElement dropdown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(dropdownId)));
  dropdown.click();

  //Now wait until nested option to be present by id
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(dropdown, By.id(optionsId))).click();
}
```

Usage :-

> I need to select the last option in the dropdown list box .when I click the drop down box 12th item is not visible

```
selectOptionsByIdFromDropdown("form:munit_panel", "form:munit_12");
```

Comment: Is there is dynamically generated for option element?? and try once using `presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy`, see updated answer,,

Comment: @Naveen and if id here dynamically changes then try using `xpath` with desired option text as `By.xpath(".//li[text() = 'Mts']")` for `Mts` option instead of `By.id()` to located option..

Comment: this is the exception i get org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: form:munit_panel (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: I have tried this code `selectOptionsByIdFromDropdown("form:munit", "feet");` and i get the expection as org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: .//li[text() = 'feet'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: @Naveen Ok, first of all let me know dropdown to be clicked and option opened or not using `form:munit` id?? and see answer again I have update it using `presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy`..

Comment: form:munit is not clicked and the drop down list is not showing..i tried using form:munit_label to show the dropdown list

Comment: @Naveen So means you need to identify correct id to open dropdrown first then provided it into method..

Comment: oki..Now i'm able to click on a dropdown with a id form:munit_label, but im unable to select the last option in the dropdown list box

Comment: @Naveen by which locator are you trying to select last option?? `By.id()` or `By.xpath()`??

Comment: i tried both but still exception  org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: .//li[text() = 'feet'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: Ok try once using `By.cssSelector()` as `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("li[data-label='feet']")))` and let me know..